# NSConcreteNotification is received, but not defined?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, preferences

I'm writing preferences for my app which registers it for launch at login (using `LSSharedItemList` API). All goes fine and my app toggles its presence in user's login items upon checkbox status. Now I want to tackle another problem when user actually removes the app from "Login items" in `Accounts.prefPane`.

Using Notification Watcher I see that distributed notification center sends `com.apple.loginItemsListDidChnage` (mind the typo) notification, hence I add observer for that notification with same selector (which is `IBAction`) that handles checkbox in preferences window (which, actually, [un]registers the app from/to login items).

The problem appears when I try to compare the class of the sender of the action that toggles my app as login item. Using `[sender description]` and `[sender class]` I see `NSConcreteNotification` class, but as soon as I try to do comparison upon it - code breaks saying that there is no such class defined:

```
if ([[sender class] isEqualTo:[NSConcreteNotification class]]) {
  ...
}
```

If I try to compare sender to `NSNotification` - then flow doesn't fall into that branch.

Maybe I'm missing some essential knowledge on distributed notifications in Mac OS X?

Running Mac OS X 10.6.2

Comment: Not to mention that I don't think `isEqualTo:` is available as a class method, so this should throw a does-not-respond-to-selector exception. (And even the instance version is for scripting. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSComparisonMethods_Protocol/ For general purposes, you would use `isEqual:`.) If it were appropriate to test whether this is the exact same class, you would use the `==` operator here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`NSConcreteNotification` is a private subclass of the abstract `NSNotification` class. You are not supposed to use the `NSConcreteNotification` class. If you want to check if a class is an `NSNotification`, use `-isKindOfClass:`:

```
if ([sender isKindOfClass:[NSNotification class]]) {
  ...
}
```